# Find consecutive rows in dataframe with a specific string value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to sort through a column in a dataframe that contains names in a string that read in the dataframe as so:

'Name/\nAnotherName'

How can I get started on sorting this so that if two consecutive rows contain the same exact two names, the value of another column 'Output' is halved?

There are instances of a single 'name' in consecutive rows that I want to avoid.

Currently what I have is something like:

```
name_condition = (df['name'] == df['name'].shift(1)) | (df['name'] == df['name'].shift(-1))
df['Output'].loc[name_condition] = df['Output'].loc[name_condition]/2
```

This works sometimes, but still picks up instances where I have two rows containing something like:

'Bob'

'Bob'

Which I would like to avoid

Comment: Please add the sample `input/output`

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, if you've 2 columns `x`/`y` then you can try:

```
df['output'] = df.groupby(df.x.ne(df.x.shift()).cumsum())['y'].transform('mean')
```